# Let $F\subseteq K $ and $V$ is a vector space over $K$ with a basis. What is the basis of $V$ over $F$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

Additionally I am given that $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ is a basis for $K$ over $F$ and $B=\{v_1, ..., v_m\}$ is a basis for $V$ over $K$.

So I think I need to express the basis of $V$ over $F$ as some sort of combination of the two basis already given...

So the basis will be $C=\{e_iv_j\|1\leq i\leq n,1\leq j\leq m\}$, any further explanation?

Comment: This is a well known theorem that often goes by "the tower rule". The answer is $nm$. The new basis vectors are all of the pairwise products of basis vectors of the two respective vector spaces.

Comment: So... $K$ is a field with a basis $e_i$? Does that mean $K$ is also a vector space?

Comment: @RudytheReindeer yes $K$ is a vector space over $F$.